# Create a trigger that updates the columns of another table (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have two tables "books" and "bookOrder" and they look something like this:

**bookOrder**

| orderID | book name | required | availability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Harry Potter | 9 | yes |
| 2 | Twilight | 8 | yes |
| 3 | Bible | 8 | yes |

**books**

| book name | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Harry Potter | 10 |
| Twilight | 5 |
| Bible | 8 |

I want to create a trigger that every time the books table is updated, it will update the **bookorder** availability column based on the **book** quantity column.

I have created a query as follows that does what I need:

```
UPDATE bookOrder bo
SET avalability = CASE WHEN b.quantity < bo.required THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END
FROM books b
WHERE b.bookName = bo.bookName
```

However, would be better if this was automatic so a trigger was my first thought. To create a trigger, I would need a function to execute. This is where I have been trouble creating the function. My attempt is as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_books() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE bookOrder bo
        SET avalability = CASE WHEN b.quantity < bo.required THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END
        FROM books b
        WHERE b.bookName = bo.bookName
    END
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Why do I get an error at the last line where the ($$) is at?

Comment: Are you using `psql` or some other client to create the trigger function? Not all SQL clients support Postgres' dollar quoting.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need the `FROM` in your UPDATE statement: `WHERE bo.bookname = new.bookname;` would be enough.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm creating with pgAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure compiled after adding a semi-colon after the WHERE clause.
And it also had to return something.

But the update doesn't need to update each row in the target table whenever books gets updated.

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_bookorder_availability() 
> RETURNS TRIGGER
> AS $$
> BEGIN
>
>   UPDATE bookOrder bo
>   SET availability = CASE 
>                      WHEN bo.required <= NEW.quantity THEN 'yes' 
>                      ELSE 'no' 
>                      END
>   WHERE bo.bookName = NEW.bookName;
>   
>   RETURN NEW;
> END
> $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER bookorder_availability_changes
>   AFTER UPDATE
>   ON books
>   FOR EACH ROW
>   EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_bookorder_availability();
> ```

> ```
> -- before update
> select * from books;
> select * from bookOrder;
> ```
>
> ```
> bookname     | quantity
> :----------- | -------:
> Harry Potter |       10
> Twilight     |        5
> Bible        |        8
>
> orderid | bookname     | required | availability
> ------: | :----------- | -------: | :-----------
>       1 | Harry Potter |        9 | yes         
>       2 | Twilight     |        8 | yes         
>       3 | Bible        |        8 | yes
> ```

> ```
> update books set quantity = quantity;
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> -- after update
> select * from books;
> select * from bookOrder;
> ```
>
> ```
> bookname     | quantity
> :----------- | -------:
> Harry Potter |       10
> Twilight     |        5
> Bible        |        8
>
> orderid | bookname     | required | availability
> ------: | :----------- | -------: | :-----------
>       1 | Harry Potter |        9 | yes         
>       2 | Twilight     |        8 | no          
>       3 | Bible        |        8 | yes
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ab96d7a2c6a5976d9b526c89a55a6b7c)*

Comment: Thanks! That worked really well. I see how yours is a lot more efficient than mine, I'll have to keep that in mind, Cheers!